# Can anyone explain how you subtract and add in signed magnitude binary numbers, and not 2s complement?

Tags: binary

I had a question on an exam that is the following:

> Compute the following value for the 4-bit signed magnitude number below using binary subtraction or addition. Include the decimal answer.
>
> a) 0011 – 1011

First off, how do I interpret these binary numbers? With or without twos complement? If I interpret it with twos complement, I see the decimal calculation

```
3 - (-5) = 8
```

But this is wrong.

Apparently the correct answer is

```
3 - (-3) = 6
```

So then I should interpret the second number as -3 and not -5? Is this what "signed magnitude number" means? I thought both -3 and -5 depending on interpretation were called signed.

So how do I know if I should interpret the second number as -3 or -5?

And, how do I do the operation? With or without the help of twos complement? Going with that the second number is indeed -3 and not -5, I have:

```
0011 = 3
1011 = -3

0011-1011
```

How to do this? I learned in twos complement you should just invert the number and add one but if I do this to the second number and add them together I get:

0011
+ 0101
  = 1000

So 8 again and its wrong. The answer is 6.

I am extremely confused, I have no idea when to use twos complement, what "signed magnitude number" means and how to do this calculation.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

In signed Number, the first bit is the sign bit. 1 for negative and 0 for positive. (-43) encoded in an eight-bit byte is 10101011 while 43 is 00101011

So in your case 1011 is the negative of 0011 which is -3

0011 + 0011 = 6

Answer (score 0):

One of the limitations of signed magnitude representation is that you can not directly apply the arithmetic operations on them. Manually, we remove the signed bit first(which happens to be the leftmost in the given representation) and then we convert it to decimal form, perform the operation, return back to the signed magnitude form.

There is no direct way to solve it and therefore a different notation of 1's/2's complement is used.

Comment: What do you mean "directly apply?" The operator seems pretty well-defined to me: 1. Subtraction is the same as Adding a negative, so 2. Invert the sign bit and do normal binary addition, then 3. Convert to decimal for the final answer.