# What is 1's complement addition?

Tags: binary, integer-arithmetic

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1071.txt

I see "1's complement addition" is mentioned above. But I don't find its official definition. Could anybody let me know what it is defined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can anyone explain how you subtract and add in signed magnitude binary numbers, and not 2s complement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143582/can-anyone-explain-how-you-subtract-and-add-in-signed-magnitude-binary-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

In ones' complement arithmetic, the last carry bit is wrapped around and added to the result (*end-around carry*). This is also described in [RFC 1071](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071):

> On a 2's complement machine, the 1's complement sum must be computed by means of an "end around carry", i.e., any overflows from the most significant bits are added into the least significant bits.

In pseudocode, this could be implemented like this:

```
Function Sum(a: Int16, b: Int16): Int16 {
    c: Int32 := a + b
    return (c AND 0xFFFF) + (c >> 16)
}
```

#### Example

```
   F000
 + 1009
-------
   0009
 + 0001 // add carry
-------
   000A
```

The reason the ones' complement arithmetic is used in RFC 1071 is, I guess, that many computer systems used it at the time the Internet Checksum was developed in the 1970s. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Signed_number_representations&oldid=1020867817#Ones%27_complement) Wikipedia page describes why the end-around carry is necessary when the bits represent signed integers.

Comment: It seems two's-complement arithmetic was more common back then already -- page 15 of RFC1071 explains why the checksum uses ones' complement in spite of this: "One's complement arithmetic is better than two's complement because it is equally sensitive to errors in all bit positions."

Answer (score -2):

1's complement is a number representation where to take the negative of a number, you simply flip all the bits. Addition in this format would simply involve representing numbers as such, then performing binary addition.